# Why is my directive tag appearing in the dom with angular reactive-forms

Tags: angular, dom, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive

I'm utilizing Dynamic Reactive Forms for the first time and am trying to modify an existing stack blitz example. 
https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-form/stackblitz.html
The initial project is working however when I interact with positioning the elements. the directive tag appears in the DOM with angular shadow DOM appearing empty.  I am unsure how to eliminate the directive from occupying space in the dom.  Any help is much appreciated.

I am using Angular8

dynamic-form.component.html

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">

    <div class="form-row">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let question of questions" >
        <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>
        ## This is the directive tag that appears in the dom ##
      </ng-container>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">
    <strong>Saved the following values</strong><br>{{payLoad}}
  </div>
</div>
```

dynamic-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup }                 from '@angular/forms';

import { MsgItemBase }              from '../../models/msg-item-base';
import { QuestionControlService }    from '../../services/question-control.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-form',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
  providers: [ QuestionControlService ]
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() questions: MsgItemBase<any>[] = [];
  form: FormGroup;
  payLoad = '';

  constructor(private qcs: QuestionControlService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

dynamic-form.component.html

```
<div class="form-row">
<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"}-->
<!---->
<app-question _nghost-ng-cli-universal-c4="" ng-reflect-question="[object Object]" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]"><div _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c4="" class="col-md-4 mb-3 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]"><label _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c4="" for="firstName">First name</label>
<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-switch": "textbox"}-->
<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "textbox"}-->
<input _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c4="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" ng-reflect-name="firstName" id="firstName" type="">
<!--bindings={ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "dropdown"}-->
<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}-->
<div _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c4="" class="errorMessage">First name is required</div></div></app-question>
<!---->
<app-question _nghost-ng-cli-universal-c4="" ng-reflect-question="[object Object]" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]"><div _ngcontent-ng-cli-
... etc....
```

I was expecting the directives to never populate the DOM directly.

Comment: your expectation was wrong. This is how angular renders it's dom, you can't prevent it and you need to work with it if you want to build an angular app

Comment: on second thought this question may be focusing on the wrong aspect of my issue.  My question is on the fixed width/height of the the element that is placing it incorrectly in the dom.  all the other directives do not take up space.